# Having trouble removing from a queue and adding to another

Tags: java, queue

I have an input file containing many strings and ints.

ex.

blah 40

hello 10

asdf 20

etc...

I have already read them into a queue to hold them. I need to take them out of the queue and add it into a priority queue whenever int i equals the ints in my data file.

This is what I have so far..

```
for(int i = 0; i<=50; i++)
{
    Object x = normalQueue.Dequeue();  //this makes x equal the line of the data file dequeued.
    if(i == x.secondint) //secondint is the Objects method that gets the integer in the data file
    {
        PQueue.Insert(x); //Inserts x to PQueue if i = the second int in the data file
    }
    else
    {
        normalQueue.Enqueue(x); //adds x back to queue1
        normalQueue.SwitchEnds(); //Swaps the 1st and last node
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is it is only printing out 2 files of the data file.

Comment: Any reason why you do not reuse Java's queue implementations? More generally your goal is very unclear; if you want value ordering in a queue you should consider a `PriorityQueue` for instance. But this definitely looks like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: Queue2 is a PriorityQueue sorry for being unclear about that.

Comment: Then at least fix your code so that the method names match. Also, the fact that your variables start with an upper case letter violates the usual Java conventions. Your code is hard to follow because of this...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the code? Sort?

Comment: The program is suppose to read a file into a normal queue(normalQueue). Then take the first queue and add into a priority queue (PQueue) when int x equals the int value of the data file.

Comment: Then it prints out the lines based on the highest priority(whichever has the highest second int)

Comment: Your description sounds like this is an assignment and you're yet to have a full understanding of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you intend to happen when running your code, but what will happen is this:

Given the following input:

```
blah 40
hello 10
asdf 20
```

(I'm assuming you add elements to the back of the queue when reading from the file, so the ordering from the data-file will be retained)

In the first 40 iterations of your loop you are taking `"blah 40"` out of `Queue1`, adding `"blah 40"` back into `Queue1` and then swapping `"blah 40"` with either `"asdf 20"` or `"hello 10"` (depending on how many iterations you've gone through) so that `"blah 40"` is again at the beginning of `Queue1`.

In your 41th iteration of your loop, `i` is going to be 40 and you insert `"blah 40"` into `Queue2`.

In iteration 42 until the last iteration of your loop nothing is really done, except shuffling `Queue1` around, because `i` isn't 10 or 20 before `"blah 40"` is removed, so at the end of the loop `Queue1` contains `"hello 10"` and `"asdf 20"`, whilst `Queue2` contains `"blah 40"`.

I realize this walk-through might be a little confusing, but try to print out the contents of both queues after each iteration and it should become clearer.

**Edit:**
It sounds to me like what you're trying to achieve is priority ordering on your second ints (i.e. 40, 10 and 20) so that when you loop through `Queue2` and remove one and one element they print out like so:

```
"hello 10"
"asdf 20"
"blah 40"
```

(or the reverse).
If this is the case, then there's really no need for `Queue1` at all, you just need to make sure you supply your priority queue with a custom comparator that sorts your objects on their second ints. (alternatively you could implement the comparable interface in your custom objects).

Example comparator:

```
new Comparator<YourCustomObject>() 
{
      @Override
      public int compare(YourCustomObject  o1, YourCustomObject  o2) 
      {
        return Integer.compare(o1.secondint, o2.secondint); 
      }
}
```

Comment: Ok this makes since. I did as you said and the Queue1 or normalQueue still has the rest of them in there. So now how would I get the other 2 since I can 't get back to 10 or 20

Comment: Thank You I had a compare method and it prints out correctly. I didn't think about doing it that way.